# Why the radiative zone of the sun rotates uniformly, while the convective zone of the sun rotates differentially?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, sun

Wikipedia says this about the tachocline

> This is a region where the sharp regime change between the uniform rotation of the radiative zone and the differential rotation of the convection zone results in a large shear between the two—a condition where successive horizontal layers slide past one another.

Can someone please give the reason that for what does the radiative zone rotates uniformly but not the convective zone?

Comment: Have  you looked at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection)?  It's not really an answer but the _convection zone_ name was defined precisely because of its non-uniform rotation (and because fluid-like motion dominates over radiation effects).